# Query Cassandra with Both Primary Key and Secondary Key Constraints

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table in Cassandra defined as

```
CREATE TABLE foo ("A" text, "B" text, "C" text,
    "D" text, "E" text, "F" text,
    PRMIARY KEY ("A", "B"),
    INDEX ("C"))
```

I inserted billions of records into this table. And now I want to query the table with CQL

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE "A"='abc' AND "B"='def' AND "C"='ghi'
```

I keep receiving 1200 error saying that

> ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica
>   nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0
>   responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1,
>   'consistency': 'ONE'}

After googling, I suspect the reason of this error is that the query is directed to some partitions that does not hold any data.

My questions are

1. Is there any constraint querying CQL with both primary key and secondary key specified?
2. If I specified the partition key in my CQL, here "A"='abc' (correct me if wrong), why C* still tries other partition that apparently does not hold the data?
3. Any hints to solve this timeout problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note:  For my examples, I got rid of the double-quotes around the column names.  It really doesn't do anything other than preserve case in the column names (not the values) and only just serves to muck-up the works.*

> Is there any constraint querying CQL with both primary key and secondary key specified?

First of all, I need to clear-up what, exactly, your "primary key" and "secondary key" are.  If you are referring to `C` as a "secondary key," then "yes" you can, with some restrictions.  If you mean your *partition* key (`A`) and your *cluster* key (`B`), then yes, you can.

Querying by your partition and clustering keys (or even just your partition key(s) works:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM foo WHERe A='abc' AND B='def';

 a   | b   | c   | d   | e   | f
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 abc | def | ghi | jkl | mno | pqr

(1 rows)
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM foo WHERe A='abc';

 a   | b   | c   | d   | e   | f
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 abc | ddd | ghi | jkl | mno | pqr
 abc | def | ghi | jkl | mno | pqr

(2 rows)
```

When I create your table and index, insert a few rows, and run your query:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE A='abc' AND B='def' AND C='ghi';

 a   | b   | c   | d   | e   | f
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 abc | def | ghi | jkl | mno | pqr

(1 rows)
```

That works.

> If I specified the partition key in my CQL, here "A"='abc' (correct me if wrong), why C* still tries other partition that apparently does not hold the data?

I don't believe that is the problem.  You *are* restricting it to a single partition, so it should only query data off of the `abc` partition.

> I inserted billions of records into this table.

What you are seeing, is the reason that secondary index usage is considered to be an "anti-pattern" in Cassandra.  Secondary indexes do not work the same way that they do in the relational world.  They just do not scale well to large clusters or data sets.

> Any hints to solve this timeout problem?

Yes.  Recreate your table with `C` as a second clustering key.  And do **not** create an index on `C`.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (A text, B text, C text, D text, E text, F text,
  PRMIARY KEY (A, B, C));
```

Reload your data, and then this should work for you:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE A='abc' AND B='def' AND C='ghi';
```

Not only should it work, but it should not timeout and it should be fast.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer! I appreciate your time very much! I will consider re-create the table in our next release. However, is there any setting I could use to extend the timeout, to, say, 600s? As you've guessed, I'm new from relational world to C*. And a little confused after reading your answer: does the partition key + cluster key in C* the same as primary key in RDBMS, i.e. partition key + cluster key uniquely identify a record, no?

Comment: Partition + clustering = primary key. The partition key defined the logical partition, used to determine which physical servers hold the data. The clustering key sorts the remaining records within each partition. Generally, raising the timeout is probably not advisable - you should be able to query a page of records within the timeout. Check system.log to make sure you're actually timing out and not hitting TombstoneOverwhelmingException. If you're hitting TOmbstoneOverwhelmingException, you may be trying to implement an anti pattern.

Comment: @JeffJirsa Thank you! Just to confirm, in your "partition + cluster = primary" equation, it interprets like "In C*, partition key and cluster key together works as primary key in RDBMS"? The timeout argument makes sense.

Comment: I know the problem of secondary indexing leading the query to hit multiple nodes if I don't specify the partition key, but why don't secondary key usage scale if always provide the partition key?